# Updating array with useState in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React and trying to figure out how to update state when a selection changes on an dropdown selection.

Here is my code:

page.js

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import SelectionRow from './selection-row';


export default function Home() {

  const [positions, setPositions] = useState([
    {id: 1, role : "Executive", selected_val: 2},
    {id: 2, role : "Director", selected_val: 1},
    {id: 3, role : "Manager", selected_val: 0},
    {id: 4, role : "Staff", selected_val: 0}]);

  function selectionChanged(e) {
    
  }

  return (
    <main>
      <form>
        {positions.map((position) => (
        <SelectionRow key={position.id} id={position.id} label={position.role} selected_val={position.selected_val} onSelectionChanged={selectionChanged}/>
        ))}
      </form>
    </main>
  )
}
```

selection-row.js

```
const options = [
    { id: 0, name: "David"}, 
    { id: 1, name: "Andrew"}, 
    { id: 2, name: "Steven"}, 
    { id: 3, name: "Simon"}, 
  ];

export default function SelectionRow({id, label, selected_val, onSelectionChanged}) {

    return (
        <div>
        <label>{label}</label>
        <select onChange={onSelectionChanged} value={selected_val} id={id} name={id}>
        {options.map((value) => (
          <option value={value.id} key={value.id}>
            {value.name}
          </option> ))}
        </select>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The sample application has an array of "company positions" that I want to populate with names chosen for a dropdown box for each. When the name is the dropdown box is changed, I want the selected_val in the positions array to be updated with id of the person selected.

Beyond passing a callback to the component, i'm unsure what I need to add in the selectionChanged function to update the positions array.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the `setPositions` function itself to `SelectionRow`.

Then on the `select` change handler, use the `previous` value from the state to `findIndex` the changes index of the original array, then update the `selected_val`.

**Demo:**

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Home() {

  const [positions, setPositions] = useState([
    {id: 1, role : "Executive", selected_val: 2},
    {id: 2, role : "Director", selected_val: 1},
    {id: 3, role : "Manager", selected_val: 0},
    {id: 4, role : "Staff", selected_val: 0}]);

  return (
    <main>
      <form>
        {positions.map((position) => (
        <SelectionRow key={position.id} id={position.id} label={position.role} selected_val={position.selected_val} setPositions={setPositions}/>
        ))}
      </form>
    </main>
  )
}


function SelectionRow({id, label, selected_val, setPositions}) {
    const options = [
    { id: 0, name: "David"}, 
    { id: 1, name: "Andrew"}, 
    { id: 2, name: "Steven"}, 
    { id: 3, name: "Simon"}, 
  ];

    const onSelect = (e) => {

        console.log('Changed', id, 'to', e.target.value )

        setPositions(prev => {
            const dup = [...prev];
            console.log(2, dup)
            const changedId = dup.findIndex(d => d.id === id);
            if (changedId >= 0) {
                dup[changedId] = { ...dup[changedId], selected_val: +e.target.value };
            }
            return dup;
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
        <label>{label}</label>
        <select onChange={onSelect} value={selected_val} id={id} name={id}>
        {options.map((value) => (
          <option value={value.id} key={value.id}>
            {value.name}
          </option> ))}
        </select>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

---

If you need more control in the Home component, or want to re-use this logic in another component, you could also define a updateX function:

```js
const updateSelectedVal = (id, selected_val) => {
      setPositions(prev => {
          const dup = [...prev];
          const changedId = dup.findIndex(e => id === id);
          if (changedId >= 0) {
              dup[changedId] = { ...dup[changedId], selected_val };
          }
          return dup;
      })
  }
```

Then pass that to the `SelectionRow` with an argument for the new `selected_val`.

Then you just need to call that function in the row:

```js
const onSelect = (e) => {
    updatePosition(+e.target.value);
}
```

**Demo**:

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Home() {

  const [positions, setPositions] = useState([
    {id: 1, role : "Executive", selected_val: 2},
    {id: 2, role : "Director", selected_val: 1},
    {id: 3, role : "Manager", selected_val: 0},
    {id: 4, role : "Staff", selected_val: 0}]);

  console.log(positions)
  
  const updateSelectedVal = (id, selected_val) => {
      setPositions(prev => {
          const dup = [...prev];
          const changedId = dup.findIndex(d => d.id === id);
          if (changedId >= 0) {
              dup[changedId] = { ...dup[changedId], selected_val };
          }
          return dup;
      })
  }

  return (
    <main>
      <form>
        {positions.map((position) => (
        <SelectionRow key={position.id} id={position.id} label={position.role} selected_val={position.selected_val} updatePosition={(n) => updateSelectedVal(position.id, n)}/>
        ))}
      </form>
    </main>
  )
}


function SelectionRow({id, label, selected_val, updatePosition}) {
    const options = [
    { id: 0, name: "David"}, 
    { id: 1, name: "Andrew"}, 
    { id: 2, name: "Steven"}, 
    { id: 3, name: "Simon"}, 
  ];

    const onSelect = (e) => {
        updatePosition(+e.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <div>
        <label>{label}</label>
        <select onChange={onSelect} value={selected_val} id={id} name={id}>
        {options.map((value) => (
          <option value={value.id} key={value.id}>
            {value.name}
          </option> ))}
        </select>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume that if I wanted to for example update a backend database to reflect the changes, the preferred approach is your second example ?

Comment: That is something you better decide for yourself, if your database logic is mainly in the main component I would indeed go for the 2nd option, but that depends very much on your (database) situation.

Comment: Second example has a minor bug. const changedId = dup.findIndex(e => id === id). It should be  const changedId = dup.findIndex(e => e.id === id).

Comment: Oeps! Nice catch, I've updated it in my answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
 import { useState } from 'react';
        import SelectionRow from './selection-row';
        
        
        export default function Home() {
        
          const [positions, setPositions] = useState([
            {id: 1, role : "Executive", selected_val: 2},
            {id: 2, role : "Director", selected_val: 1},
            {id: 3, role : "Manager", selected_val: 0},
            {id: 4, role : "Staff", selected_val: 0}]);
        
          function selectionChanged(e,id) {
    let prev=[...positions]
    let filteredValue=prev.map(v=>{
      if(v.id==id){
        return newdata={...v,selected_val:e.target.value}
      }else{
        return v
      }
    })
    setPositions(filteredValue)
    
            
          }
        
          return (
            <main>
              <form>
                {positions.map((position,id) => (
                <SelectionRow key={position.id} id={position.id} label={position.role} selected_val={position.selected_val} onSelectionChanged={(e)=>selectionChanged(e,id)}/>
                ))}
              </form>
            </main>
          )
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).